# Could not able to get checked child radio button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I have radio buttons sets inside containers with class named `answers` the container may be a `span` or `ol` i.e:

```
<ol class="answers"> <!-- radio buttons set here li per each button --></ol>

OR
<span class="a-panel answers"><!-- radio buttons set here --></span>
```

All radio sets per each container have unique attribute `name` value.

I could not able to get the checked value using the following code:

```
$(".answers").each(function(){
alert($(this).children("input[type=radio]:checked").val())
})
```

It always alert undefined. This is a [Jsbin DEMO](http://output.jsbin.com/hubomeleka)

Comment: 1. You can use the `:radio` pseudo-selector instead of `[type=radio]`, and 2. You are using `children()` and probably want to use `find()`. `children()` only looks one level deep so won't for example find any `input` tags under an `li` element of a `ol.answers`

Comment: @swornabsent Yes it is `find` is the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure javascript solution. Give all your radios the same name and different id. Then get the id with this function:

```
function obtainSelectedRadioId(name) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
    var res = '';
    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) 
        if (radios[i].checked) 
            res = radios[i].id;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Than you for the solution and I +1 for it, but I could not sign it as an answer, because I'm using Jquery solution. Indeed, the comment of [swornabsent 8](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1107958/swornabsent) is very useful too.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. If someone has a solution like the one you're wanting, I'll probably end up changing the above function anyway :)